# swift snapshot firebase; which child it came from

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need a pretty simple thing and I cant figure it out. I created a snapshot of firebase, and i matched the userID with the snapshots name of inside a child. I just need the childs ID (which i created using childbyautoID)

here is my code:

```
func checkIfUserIsLoggedIn(){
    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil {

    } else {
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(uid!).child("data").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                self.fnamefinal = dictionary["email"] as? String
                if self.fnamefinal != nil {

                    self.ref.child("Request").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

                        let results = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]
                        let name = results?["name"]
                        let garage = results?["garage"]
                        let time = results?["time"]
                        let latitude = results?["latitude"]
                        let longitude = results?["longitude"]
                        let childID = results?[""]

                        print(snapshot)
                        print(childID as! String?)

                        if name as! String? == self.fnamefinal {
                        let myCalls = RidesRequestedd(name: name as! String?, garage: garage as! String?, time: time as! String?, latitude: latitude as! Double?, longitude: longitude as! Double?)
                        self.frequests1.append(myCalls)
                        self.rideslabel.text = myCalls.garage

                        } else {

                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    print("no")
                }
            }
        })
    //}
}
```

Here is the snapshot of the matched name with user ID:

```
Snap (-LMBAF69-kYKnWoK2n9M) {
    garage = "Coliseum/Bobcat Stadium";
    latitude = "29.89";
    longitude = "-97.953";
    name = "test3@gmail.com";
    time = "12:13 AM";
}
```

I just need the LMBAF69.... string. Simple but i cant figure it out

[image]

Comment: The children of `Requests` in your screenshot don't have a property called `userID`. So your `self.ref.child("Request").queryOrdered(byChild: "userID")` is pretty meaningless. It still returns data (since you don't filter), but the `orderBy` call is useless without the property that you try to order on.

Comment: That value is known as the *key* and is available in `snapshot.key`.

Comment: im matching the users email with the requests name so that the user can see/edit their node data and as I understand it I need the autoID for the selected request?

Comment: Frank is wright using snapshot.key should give you the data you need.

Comment: So how would i pull the key from the request, that was picked in the array, that matched names if im pulling from all the "requests" node and sorting/picking them with an array and not from firebase? is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Using *self.ref.child("Request").observe(.childAdded...* will iterate over every node in *Requests*, reading each one as a snapshot. Within that closure, adding *print(snapshot.key)* will print the key for each node (-LM0No, -LMBA etc etc). See @FrankvanPuffelen's comment above about snapshot.key. However, iterating over all nodes and searching within each node may indicate a need for denormalizing your data. Or, just implementing a query for all nodes where the email child is equal to the email you are looking for may work the best.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!